# What does fork="true" do?

Tags: ant

I saw the attribute `fork="true"` in an ant `<java>` task. What does it mean?

Comment: Yes, this is a good option. I am also reading it. I come across this when doing DOJO build.

Comment: I found it was required when trying to use cpsuite-1.2.6.jar (ClassPathSuite) to run all my JUnit4 tests. Without the fork="true" option, ant would discover no unit tests. I presume this is because ClassPathSuite was searching the class-path of ant rather than the code under test. (1 day wasted - argh!)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It causes the task to run in a different process, and a different Java virtual machine. From [the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html):

> **fork**: if enabled triggers the class execution in another VM (disabled by default)

Why this is useful: Some behavior and parameters require a separate JVM, run in a separate process. For example, your task might need a different classpath, more memory, or different JVM arguments. You might want the build to continue if the task fails or crashes. You might want to specify a timeout for the task.